# Weyl, Space-Time-Matter: The Riemann "quadrilinear form", and "functions which stand in quadratic relationship with an element of surface"

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

The following is from pages 83 and 84 of [Space—Time—Matter by Hermann Weyl](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/43006):

> Sometimes conditions of symmetry more complicated than
> those considered heretofore occur. In the realm of quadrilinear
> forms $F(\xi, \eta, \xi', \eta')$ those play a particular part which satisfy the
> conditions (Eqs 39)
> $$\begin{aligned}
> F(\eta, \xi,\xi',\eta')=& F(\xi,\eta,\eta',\xi') = -F(\xi,\eta,\xi',\eta'), \\
> F(\xi',\eta',\xi,\eta)=& F(\xi,\eta,\xi',\eta'),\\
> 0=&F(\xi,\eta,\xi',\eta') + F(\xi,\xi',\eta',\eta) + F(\xi,\eta',\eta,\xi').
> \end{aligned}$$
> For it may be shown that for every quadratic form of an arbitrary
> two-dimensional space-element
> $$
> \xi^{ik} = \xi^{i} \eta^{k} - \xi^{k} \eta^{i}
> $$
> there is one and only one quadrilinear form $F$ which satisfies
> these conditions of symmetry, and from which the above quadratic
> form is derived by identifying the second pair of variables $\xi'$, $\eta'$
> with the first pair $\xi$, $\eta$. We must consequently use co-variant
> tensors of the fourth order having the symmetrical properties (Eqs 39)
> if we wish to represent functions which stand in quadratic relationship
> with an element of surface.

It clearly foreshadows the Riemann curvature tensor, but I'm not sure how to read it.  Specifically I'm not sure what is meant by **"quadratic form of an arbitrary two-dimensional space-element".**  On pages 81 and 82 he discusses the squared magnitude of a two-dimensional space-element $\frac{1}{2}\xi^{ij}\xi_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}g_{ik}g_{jl}\xi^{ij}\xi^{kl}$.  That's my best guest as to what is intended.  I am similarly confused by **"functions which stand in quadratic relationship with an element of surface."**

If someone would shed some light on this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Weyl says the following: A quadratic form of an arbitrary two-dimensional space-element $\xi^{ik}=\xi^i\eta^k-\xi^k\eta^i$ is
$$
Q(\xi^{ik})=a_{jlmn}\xi^{jl}\xi^{mn}\quad\quad\text{ (with summation convention). }
$$
(Instead of writing $Q(\xi)$ I kept the indices in $\xi^{ik}$ to distiguish it from the one-dimensional $\xi^i\,.$)

1. For every such $Q$ there is a quadrilinear form $F(\xi,\eta,\xi',\eta')$ such that $Q(\xi^{ik})=F(\xi,\eta,\xi,\eta)\,.$ This is trivial. Just define
   $$\tag{1}
   F(\xi,\eta,\xi',\eta')=a_{jlmn}\,\xi^{jl}(\xi')^{mn}\,.
   $$
2. The $F$ from (1) is unique. To see that let's write $F$ as a bilinear form
   of two-dimensional space elements
   $$
   F(\xi,\eta,\xi',\eta')=Q(\xi^{ik},(\xi')^{ik})\,.
   $$
   From
   $$\tag{2}
   Q\big(\xi^{ik}+(\xi')^{ik},\xi^{ik}+(\xi')^{ik}\big)=
   Q(\xi^{ik})+
   2\,\underbrace{Q\big(\xi^{ik},(\xi')^{ik}\big)}_{F(\xi,\eta,\xi',\eta')}+
   Q\big((\xi')^{ik})
   $$
   it follows that $F(\xi,\eta,\xi',\eta')$ is determined by the other three quadratic form terms in (2).

A more modern treatment of symmetry/anti-symmetry relationships of multilinear tensors is based on differential forms and their wedge product. The book *Graviation* of Misner, Thorne and Wheeler is my favourite reference.

Comment: I once showed Dr. Wheeler my copy of Weyl's book, and asked him if he was familiar with it.  He took the book from my hand and paused for quite some time.  He then drummed his index finger on the book and said "I read this book about once a decade, and learn something new from it every time."  At the current point in Weyl's book, he is merely laying the groundwork.  I am confident he has a profound reason for the way he introduces these symmetries. MTW probably give 5 different explanations for the symmetries of the Riemann tensor.